# Set different backgrounds in the document using Aspose

Tags: java, kotlin, aspose, aspose.words

I wanted to set different background in my document with the following conditions

1. The first page of the document should contain the first.png as a background.
2. The remaining pages of the document should contain a second.png as a background.

I'm able to set backgrounds as per my expectations if the first page of the input document doesn't contain an image in the header.
If the document's first page contains an image in the header it is removing that header on the first page only.

I'm using the following code snippet to achieve my functionality.

```
val headerPrimary = document.firstSection.headersFooters[HEADER_PRIMARY]
if (!document.firstSection.pageSetup.differentFirstPageHeaderFooter && headerPrimary != null) {
    // If so create first page header and copy content of the primary header into it.
    val headerFirst = HeaderFooter(document, HEADER_FIRST);
    headerPrimary.childNodes.forEach {
        headerFirst.appendChild(it.deepClone(true));
    }
    // Put the first page header into the document.
    document.firstSection.headersFooters.add(headerFirst);
}

val builder = DocumentBuilder(document)
document.firstSection.pageSetup.differentFirstPageHeaderFooter = true

builder.moveToHeaderFooter(HEADER_FIRST)
setImageInBackground(builder, firstImageDataString)

builder.moveToHeaderFooter(HEADER_PRIMARY)
setImageInBackground(builder, SecondImageDataString)

private fun setImageInBackground(builder: DocumentBuilder, imageString: String) {
    val background = builder.insertImage(imageString)
    background.wrapType = NONE
    background.behindText = true
    background.relativeHorizontalPosition = RelativeHorizontalPosition.PAGE
    background.relativeVerticalPosition = RelativeVerticalPosition.PAGE
    background.left = (builder.pageSetup.pageWidth - background.width) / 2
    background.top = (builder.pageSetup.pageHeight - background.height) / 2
}
```

For input-document/expected-result and images, I've uploaded an attachment in the response forum [Aspose forum link](https://forum.aspose.com/t/how-to-insert-different-background-images-in-the-header-of-document/229745/7)

For Input-Output of the code: [Files.zip](https://forum.aspose.com/uploads/discourse_instance3/51048)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because your input document contains only the primary header. When you move the DocumentBuilder’s cursor into the first page header, Aspose.Words create new empty first page header. To keep the content of the primary header on the first page you should simply copy the content of the primary header into the newly created first page header. Here is a simple code that does this.

```cs
// Check whether there is only primary header.
HeaderFooter headerPrimary = (HeaderFooter)document.FirstSection.HeadersFooters[HeaderFooterType.HeaderPrimary];
if (!document.FirstSection.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter
    && headerPrimary != null)
{
    // If so create first page header and copy content of the primary header into it.
    HeaderFooter headerFirst = new HeaderFooter(document, HeaderFooterType.HeaderFirst);
    foreach (Node primaryHeaderChild in headerPrimary.ChildNodes)
        headerFirst.AppendChild(primaryHeaderChild.Clone(true));

    // Put the first page header into the document.
    document.FirstSection.HeadersFooters.Add(headerFirst);
}

// Your original code goes after.
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(document);
document.FirstSection.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = true;

builder.MoveToHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterType.HeaderFirst);
SetImageInBackground(builder, firstImageDataString);

builder.MoveToHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterType.HeaderPrimary);
SetImageInBackground(builder, secondImageDataString);
```

Comment: As you've suggested, I've implemented the code but still the image is not visible in first page's header. I've updated the code in my question with the implementation you've suggested.

Comment: I've checked the updated code with different document (in that document, the header and footer both exist in every page). After executing the updated code, in the first page of the output document Now I can see the footer content in the header. Other pages seems fine.

Comment: Please make sure HEADER_PRIMARY constant has a correct value, i.e. HEADER_PRIMARY = 1. Or better use value from HeaderFooterType class https://apireference.aspose.com/words/java/com.aspose.words/HeaderFooterType, like HeaderFooterType.HEADER_PRIMARY

Comment: it is working fine. just the placement of your code is incorrect.
Could you please approve the updated answer. so that I can accept the answer

Comment: My original code must work. I approved your edits, but it seems now code will not work because condition will not pass. Please check